# keyboard problem with '@' symbol

Tags: keyboard

I have a Dell Latitude E5250 laptop working on ubuntu. I could not figure out how to type  '@' symbol. keyboard setting is "Turkish", with Q keyboard.

Comment: Press `SHIFT + 2`. That's all. But your question will be closed because it has nothing to do with Ubuntu.

Comment: @begueradj you'd be surprised. If the keyboard layout is not set to US, shift+2 may produce something else altogether. I think it gives `"` in the UK layout. And since the layout can be set in Ubuntu...

Comment: what OS are you running ?

Comment: @mustafa özgür Berke try right Alt + 2, left Alt and Right Alt have a different result in Ubuntu, also by clicking at the language keyboard menu icon you can click on Show Layout Chart and there you will see if you should use right or left Alt with which key.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I type an \`@\` (at sign) symbol?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/103220/how-do-i-type-an-at-sign-symbol)

Answer (score 3):

Try Alt on right <kbd>Alt gr</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd> Beware that left Alt and right Alt have a different result in Ubuntu.

By clicking at the language keyboard menu icon, you can click on `Show Layout Chart` and you will see in right lower corner what will actually work with right Alt.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. Combination of the right AltGr button and Q worked..